# Android :xml file not working

Tags: java, android, xml

i am new to android and facing  some problem with  xml , i   added some  basic  code in xml file and set view to this xml file `(edit_task.xml)` like this

```
public class EditTask extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.edit_task);
    }
```

code in `edit_task.xml` is like this

```
 <ScrollView 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

       <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >

           <TextView
            android:text="@string/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             />
        <EditText 

            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="@string/body"
             />
        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/body"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minLines="5"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
           android:gravity="top" /> 

        <TextView 
           android:text="@string/date"

           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            />
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/reminder_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Reminder_Time"
            />

        <TextView 
            android:text="@string/time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            />
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/remindertime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/remindertime"
            />

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/confirm"
            android:text="@string/confirm"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            />

       </LinearLayout>

     </ScrollView>
```

now when i compile this it shows `hello world instead of this xml , Hello world id added in my  strings.xml but  its not being pointed in above mentioned xml` , so whats wrong with it ,  please  guide me about it ..

This is how i added it to `Manifest.xml`

```
<activity
 android:name="com.example.mytastreminder.EditTask"
 android:label="@string/app_name" >

 </activity>
```

Comment: are you sure that you are actually executing EditTask?

Comment: Did you check you `AndroidManifest` file? Maybe you haven't add your activity and let the default HelloWorld Activity.

Comment: @Fllo yes i have  updated my question please see if its correct way to do it ,yes i am sure i am executing EditTask

Comment: `i am executing EditTask` according to the little part of manifest you show, no you are not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Manifest, change this:

```
<activity
   android:name=".HelloAndroidActivity"
   android:label="@string/title_activity_hello_android" >
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

       <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
   </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

By:

```
<activity
   android:name=".EditTask "
   android:label="@string/app_name" >
   <intent-filter>
       **<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />**

       **<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>**
   </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

You need to set the action/category of your `Activity`. In the example above, you say EditTask is the `Main` Activity of your application and also, it's the Activity which is displayed when you `Launch` the app.
Only one activity can have this specific action/category. They can also have other action like: `VIEW`, `EDIT`, `SEARCH`, etc. But **only one** have this above.

Comment: i added this <activity
 android:name="com.example.mytastreminder.EditTask"
 android:label="@string/app_name" >

 </activity> isn't it same ?  shouldn't  it  work ?

Comment: See the last section below the example. It should work if you add the action and the category. Without this, your app displays the other activity which have the action `MAIN` and the category `LAUNCHER`.

Comment: its pointing to another xml file but dont know why added same code as you mentioned here .

Comment: in manifest.xml i pasted this activity code  on top and under that code palced helloworld activity code now its  pointing to  correct xml any idea why ? please if you get my point  guide me about it

Comment: Let me explain in some words: For each activity, you need to declare it (the activity) in the manifest file. It's a kind of resume of your application, like a "list of students who need to be here every morning to say: "Don't forget me, I'm present today". U see?

Comment: yes i get your point but in my case if i compile hello world.java or EditTask.java it points to xml file for the activity that is mentioned at the top of all activities in  manifest , like i have hello world activity  code on top in manifest and compile edittext it will still point to the hello_world.xml file that is where i am stuck dont know why this silly thing is happening but its happening  to me

Comment: ok , bro thanks a lot for your guide its working for me thumbs up :)

Comment: No problem, check the manifest in Google Documentation, it's very interesting all you can do with this file ;) Good dev.